# uninitialized slot in arraylist of linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

```
int index = hash(value, size);

if (array.get(index) == null) {
    array.add(index, new LinkedList<String>());
}
```

I have an array of LinkedLists: `Arraylist<.LinkedList<.String>>`, and I want to add a LinkedList in the array index given if one hasn't been initialized in it yet. Problem is, the index hashes to some number, but the index it goes to doesn't exist, since no LinkedList has been initialized in that index yet, but that's why i am doing `if(array.get(index) == null)` add a LinkedList, but apparently that's an incorrect comparison to do.

I tried `.isEmpty()`, `null`, and `.equals(null)`, they don't work.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have an `ArrayList`, not an array. Did you instantiate your `ArrayList` with a predefined size? If not, its size is 0, so you can't add by an index at first because it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I have bad news for you: reimplementing `HashMap<Integer, Something>`. You can just use it and it'll be fine.

Comment: its seems very odd, why you are using hash function to determine index of arraylist?

Comment: but then the .add(index, new llist) throws error, because index is outofbounds and doesnt exist yet in the arraylist. .get(index) or .add(index) cause the same problem.

Comment: Why do you need an ArrayList in this case? you should use an array of LinkedList

Comment: can  u show `hash(value, size)` with code?

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` doesn't auto-grow, you have to grow it yourself:

```
int index = hash(value, size);

// grow
if (array.size() <= index) {
    array.ensureCapacity(index + 1);
    while (array.size() <= index)
        array.add(null);
}

if (array.get(index) == null) {
    array.set(index, new LinkedList<String>());
}
```

Note my change of `array.add(index, ...)` to `array.set(index, ...)` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E))): `add` will insert (and shift the rest of the array) while `set` will overwrite the element at the given index.

As long as you control `hash` you know the upper limits of its return value (let's call this `limit`) and you should only need to initialise your array once:

```
// initialise
ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.ensureCapacity(limit);
for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
    array.add(null);

// ...

// use
int index = hash(value, size); // hash(...) returns values in 0..limit-1
if (array.get(index) == null) {
    array.set(index, new LinkedList<String>());
}
```

As Tamas Rev stated: you don't have to reinvent the wheel, just use a `HashMap`. As an additional bonus, `HashMap` will most likely be faster and generally be more memory efficient (the above scheme allocates an array of `limit` elements while `HashMap` can deal with any key type of any size).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's probably because you advised OP to grow out his `ArrayList` to possibly hundreds of millions of entries, maybe even billions (depending on the nature of `hash()`), turning it into an enormous memory-suck.